# How can I best quantitatively compare multiple 'de-bleeding' attempts?

Tags: discrete-signals, audio, audio-processing

Let $\mathit{S}$ and $\mathit{T}$ be audio tracks, and suppose that $\mathit{S}$ is the superposition of

1. An audio signal $x(t)$ of interest, and
2. A signal that is audibly quieter than, but otherwise identical to, the signal represented by $\mathit{T}$

Isolation of signal $x(t)$ might then be attempted by forming the superposition of $\mathit{S}$ and the inversion of a de-amplified copy of $\mathit{T}$.

How are the results of two attempts to isolate $x(t)$ (that differ only in the degree to which $\mathit{T}$ has been de-amplified) best compared?

Initially (and likely naively), I deemed the attempt whose peak value was smaller to be preferable. Thanks to a helpful commenter on another site, I then began to prefer the attempt whose RMS[1] was lower. Is there a better way?

(PS  Quote marks appear in the title since I'm not sure de-bleeding is what I've actually described...)

[1] By 'RMS' I mean the RMS of the collection of samples that result from an isolation attempt, where each sample is a single-precision floating-point value between -1 and 1

Comment: "but otherwise identical to" I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean. Are saying that $x$ and $T$ are identical other than over all level ?

Comment: @Hilmar I hope this is clearer: the mth sample of S is the arithmetic sum of [the mth sample of x (whose value is sought)] & [the product of the mth sample of T & some number 'c' satisfying 0<c<1]. If this relationship is loosely notated as S[m]=x[m]+cT[m], then S's nth sample S[n] is x[n]+cT[n]; i.e. every one of T's samples is scaled by the same factor. Put another way: given a mix u+v of two signals (but neither u nor v alone), & given also a signal V that is formed from v by multiplying each of v's samples by some unknown constant k>1, try to find u by mixing u+v & (-V)*(some guess at 1/k)